# TopLeft & Bottom right longitude and lattitude value of MapView in Android SDK

Tags: java, android

I am implementing a map based Android application. In that I am trying to get display the pins at TopLeft and Bottom right. The following is my code that I tried. But I am not able to display it. Can you please suggest a way to get these cordinate.

```
public GeoPoint topLeft(GeoPoint mapCenter, int latspan, int langspan) {
 int lat = (mapCenter.getLatitudeE6()) + (latspan/2);
 int lang = (mapCenter.getLongitudeE6()) - (langspan/2);
 return new GeoPoint(lat, lang);
}

public GeoPoint bottomRight(GeoPoint mapCenter, int latspan, int langspan) {
 int lat = (mapCenter.getLatitudeE6()) - (latspan/2);
 int lang = (mapCenter.getLongitudeE6()) + (langspan/2);
 return new GeoPoint(lat, lang);
}
```

Comment: That code on its own tells us nothing. How are you using it?

Comment: Where are you getting the Lat and Lon spans?

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for something like this ?

```
Projection proj = mapView.getProjection();
GeoPoint topLeft = proj.fromPixels(0, 0);

GeoPoint bottomRight = proj.fromPixels(mapView.getWidth()-1, mapView.getHeight()-1);

double topLat = topLeft.getLatitudeE6()/1E6;
double topLon = topLeft.getLongitudeE6()/1E6;
double bottomLat = bottomRight.getLatitudeE6()/1E6;
double bottomLon = bottomRight.getLongitudeE6()/1E6;
```

Hope it helps!